# Filtering a JSON object through a template

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, backbone.js

I need to filter JSON objects' properties and values based on a dynamic template (for security reasons). It is like viewing the JSON objects through a mask that is known only at run time.

Say I have this JSON object:

```
{ "id": "1",
  "foo": [ "1", "2", "3" ],
  "bar": [ "a", "b", "c"],
  "fuzz": [ "y", "x" ]
}
```

And this template:

```
{ "id": "",
  "fuzz": [ "y", "z"],
  "foo": ""
}
```

Now I want to have the following result (applying the template onto the object):

```
{ "id": "1",
  "fuzz": [ "y" ],
  "foo": [ "1", "2", "3" ]
}
```

What are the best solutions to filter

1. Only the properties (leaving values untouched)?
2. The properties and the values (like in the example above)?

Notes:

- The ordering of properties and values may be different between the template and the objects
- My environment is NodeJS + BackboneJS
- A have a lot of objects to filter, so performance matters

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, `c` etc? Are they just substitutes for the sake of this post? Because they make the JSON invalid.

Comment: Yes they are - I've corrected the post to make it more compliant

Comment: *"What is the best solution to filter...Only the properties (leaving values untouched)?"* Your example result changes one of the values (specifically, the value of the `fuzz` property -- you've removed the `"x"` entry from it).

Comment: Thanks for raising the ambiguity, hence I slightly changed the wording of the post. Realizing this might be a bit challenging to implement, I've split the question at two levels (with possibly two different solutions): first, filtering out whole properties (and their values), then filtering out some values inside a property. What I am after is a combination of both

Comment: What have you tried? Look at underscore's utility functions. `_.pick(obj, _.keys(filter))` for first filter, and then an `_.each` using value comparisons and `_.isArray` with `_.intersection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the WiredPrairie's suggestion, I rewrote _.pick() and _.intersection() into the following method that does the trick:

```
// Loosely based on Underscore.js _.pick() method
function project(obj, tmp) {
    var copy = {};
    var keys = _.keys(tmp);
    _.each(keys, function(key) {
        if (key in obj) {
            var vals = tmp[key];
            if (Array.isArray(vals)) {
                var copy_vals = [];
                // Next lines could be replaced by:
                // cvals = _.intersection(vals, obj[key]);
                _.each(vals, function(val) {
                    if ($.inArray(val, obj[key])!=-1) {
                        copy_vals.push(val);
                    };
                });
                copy[key] = copy_vals;
            } else {
                copy[key] = obj[key];
            };
        };
    });
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but you could try read this one [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Comment: It's not a merge they are looking for. How would this help?